# Import python module in 'watertight compartment'

Tags: python, import, copy

I am facing a tricky problem in Python:

- I need to import a Python module (say, module_A) developed by somebody else which imports and monkey-patches httplib.
- and I also need to import selenium, which uses httplib and does not like the above patches

Since I cannot really modify either modules, I was wondering if it is possible to import module_A in a 'watertight compartment' of the memory (dunno if there's a more correct term), that is, in such a way that all modules used inside module_A are imported as completely different objects, even if they were imported somewhere else.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as a 'sandbox' for modules, no.

You can undo monkey patches to a module by *reloading* the module:

```
import httplib
import module_A
reload(httplib)
```

This'll re-import `httplib`, resetting any globals to their original definition. Additional globals set by `module_A` are preserved, but changed methods and classes are reverted to their original state.

The alternative would be for you to slot a mock module into `sys.modules['httplib']` for `module_A` to patch, then removing it again from `sys.modules` and importing the real `httplib` module. But the `httplib` module itself can be that mock better than anything else.

Another idea could be to try and re-slot the patched `httplib` module under a different name in `sys.modules` after patching, and count on `module_A` holding references to the objects in that module:

```
import sys
import module_A

sys.modules['httplib_patched'] = sys.modules['httplib']
del sys.modules['httplib']
```

Now there is no `'httplib'` key in `sys.modules` and a *new* import would get a fresh unpatched version.

Comment: yes but if I reload httplib, then module_A which relies on the patched version of httplib does not work any more. I ended up copying httplib.py into the folder of module_A so that it is loaded as a different object. Dirty, but it works!

Comment: @bruno: right, no, there is an inherent incompatibility there. I had another idea, try that.